# Usage of shadow creatures in dont starve (playing as a Maxwell)

Tags: dont-starve-together

Since I am not very familiar with the 'Don't Starve' game I got a little problem with usage of shadow creatures which Maxwell bring to life.

As I am playing Maxwell I do not know how can I use my puppets. As I saw the puppet with axe, chops the trees automatically. But if I create the man with the sword how can I attack some creatures? Another question is how can I use the man with the shovel? As I saw he only dig the trees but can I control him somehow to dig the sappling, bushes etc.?

After some days I realized that the puppets are dying. They got some time to stay in the world or what? How long can I use them before they will dissapear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is the [Codex Umbra](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Codex_Umbra). The article explains it in great detail, but to answer your questions:

- The man with the sword (*Shadow Duelist*) will either defend you if attacked or will attack whatever you attack (note: like with Pigs or Bunnies, you don't need to actually attack - you can just click to attack and then stop).
- The man with the shovel (*Shadow Digger*) will only dig graves and stumps.
- The shadows will disappear 2.5 days after you summon them.